# Could CiviCRM 4.5 or 4.6 make it easier to generate large numbers of PDFs at once?

Tags: upgrade, receipts, pdf

I have a client using CiviCRM 4.4, who prefers to generate donation and membership receipts as PDFs for mailing in print form, but has found that they often have trouble generating all the PDFs they need to at once, and have to break the list of donations or memberships down into small batches in order to generate the receipts.

They are considering upgrading to 4.5 or 4.6, but are wondering whether this might help address the problems with batch generation of PDFs. I looked through the issues list in Jira for both releases and didn't see anything that seemed specifically related, but there are so many things listed that it's easy to miss something.

Does anyone have any personal experience of this, or know whether there are any improvements to PDF generation in 4.5 or 4.6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using the wkhtmltopdf option in CiviCRM:

Administer CiviCRM >> System Settings >> Misc

http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1

Its a local binary installation (needs to be done by your system admin), but gives you a lot better performance than the php pdf libraries shipped with CiviCRM

Comment: I just checked and no, the site was not set to use that, so I'll try installing it - thank you!

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is so much faster than tcpdf library, so my advise is to try to install it in your server