# Installing and Setting wkhtmltopdf Path In Civicrm

Tags: pdf

How can i install wkhtmltopdf in civicrm and set the path to the exe. I am using Civicrm with Wordpress.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Download the compiled binaries for your system from http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html to your server and extract to somewhere convenient.  The files need to be readable by the account running the webserver.  Then go to Administer >> System Settings >> Misc and enter the path to the wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: Great - if you accept it as the answer (green tick) then it helps others with the same question.

Comment: So I'm trying to install wkhtmltopdf. Did this so far - wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
tar xf wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz to /tmp
sudo mv wkhtmltopdf/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Does it matter that wkhtmltopdf is in /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf? Or must wkhtmltopdf be in /usr/local/bin?
And - for Path to wkhtmltopdf executable at Administer -> System Settings -> Misc ((Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.) - not sure exactly what to enter    

Is it /var/www/[xxx]/[mysite]/sites... something? 

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It can be anywhere, providing the id running your webserver can run it.  The 'path' under Administer > System Settings > Misc is just the OS path - eg /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Doesn't work in a Windows environment under 4.7.23 - CiviCRM claims C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe where the executable is stored does not exist or is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: [Could CiviCRM 4.5 or 4.6 make it easier to generate large numbers of PDFs at once?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/852/could-civicrm-4-5-or-4-6-make-it-easier-to-generate-large-numbers-of-pdfs-at-onc)

I came across that by googling wkhtmltopdf civicrm by the way ;)