# CiviEvent Confirmation Email causes Time-Out

Tags: civievent, email, confirmation

I'm using wordpress 5.11 and CiviCRM 5.8.2.
I am trying to get a CiviEvent to send confirmation emails but when I select the confirmation emails, the session times-out for the user (error 504).  The registration does go through, but no email is sent.

Some observations, turning off the confirmation email works.  Registration completes and it goes to the completion page.

I can go into Find Participants, Edit their payment and send a confirmation email from there and it works.

I'm configured to use CiviSMTP as my email host.  I have no issues sending out bulk emails or day to day processing emails like renewal notices.

I have checked the logs and there is nothing reported.

I found a similar post here that suggested modifying/adding session.saved_path=/my/temp/dir which I put in as displayed here.  I'm not certain that is the correct format.  As displayed it made no difference.  The 504 Timeout is consistent and happens every time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - this is a big event and it opens on Friday so I would really like to have this working by then.  I don't really want to have to do manual confirmation emails!

Thanks
Norm

Comment: /my/temp/dir usually means /tmp on unix but depends on the hosting setup, e.g. it might be /home/something/private/tmp or something like that. If you can't tell ask the hoster.

Comment: /my/temp/dir I added in.  I know my tmp is /home/sporti62/tmp, which is what I used.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure then what you meant by not being sure about the format. Anyway after editing php.ini you usually also need to restart the webserver, if you haven't already.

Comment: Are you sending a pdf confirmation with the mail?  I recall a situation where the pdf creation was failing which then caused the mail to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a perfect solution, it turns out to be the PDF processing that is causing it to time out (known issue apparently).
I disabled the PDF generation for emails and everything works fine now.

Thanks!
Norm

Answer (score 1):

If PDF processing is the issue, consider installing [wkhtmltopdf](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/10879/12).  It's much more efficient than the built-in PDF generation.

It can't ship with CiviCRM because it's written in a compiled language - so unlike CiviCRM, which can run unmodified on Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc., wkhtmltopdf is OS-specific (and to some extent, processor-specific).  However, it's easy to download and tell CiviCRM where to find it.