# I want to create a custom label for avery 8660 matte clear labels

Tags: address-labels

Ive measured the labels and entered the measurments into the custom label form.

Each time I run the mailing label generation function I get blank pages.

I stepped down to font size from 8pt to 6 pt and the result is the same.  Blank pages.

I stepped down the indentation to the top and left side of the label to .2mm.  Again, blank pages.

Not sure what to do to fix this.

Comment: Have you installed the alternative PDF processor `wkhtmltopdf`?  If not, I would give it a shot; if you have, try temporarily disabling it and see if anything changes!  Also - do you have the same issue when changing the font size to 6pt on all labels, or just your custom label?

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech, I did not install the alternative PDF processor- where could I find directions on that? Changing the font size to 6pt did not affect the other labels I tested.

Comment: You need command-line access and it's a bit technical, but the [general wkhtmltopdf instructions are here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10879/installing-and-setting-wkhtmltopdf-path-in-civicrm).

Comment: Re wkhtltopdf - Note some hosting packages provide it so you just need to configure the path to it in Civi.

Comment: Also, can you print successfully on one of the default label sizes?

Comment: I can't remember the details now, but I had quite a lot of trouble with the settings for custom labels. The values weren't the ones I measured and I had to do it a bit by trial and error, so I would suggest starting with a default one and try changing one setting at a time to work out where the problem is